# Is an email from a domain is certain proof that email is from the actual domain website's owner?

Tags: email, web, dns, smtp

Do an email like love@AnExampleReputedBank.com, can be assumed to be definitely from the domain 
WWW.AnExampleReputedBank.com ?
Or any hacker can send any email from any domain?

The question is difficult to explain, so let me explain the problem case I am trying to solve.

I am making a package manager for my configurable app. And I will allow every one to publish their packages for my app, so that users can add new functionality to app, by just downloading the packages. To solve problem of namespace collision, I am using domain name.[For ex. AnExampleReputedBank.com]

To let my end user know, that a package is from a verified user [The actual owner of AnExampleReputedBank.com], I will provide a verified tick mark against that package.

A verification mark can be obtained for a package, if my system receives an email from admin@AnExampleReputedBank.com, along with the verification code.

Will this be a sufficient measure to ensure a package is from a original package managers [For domain owners of AnExampleReputedBank.com] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

From addresses are whatever the sender of the email writes in the From field. It is as dependable as the return address scrawled on the back of a physical envelope that is posted.

There are methods (e.g. DKIM) to ensure that the email was sent by someone authorized to send email from that domain, but that doesn't prove ownership of a domain. I have a Gmail account, but I certainly don't control `gmail.com`.

Most attempts to verify ownership of a domain use the approaches used by [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/):

> To kick off the process, the agent asks the Let’s Encrypt CA what it
>   needs to do in order to prove that it controls example.com. The Let’s
>   Encrypt CA will look at the domain name being requested and issue one
>   or more sets of challenges. These are different ways that the agent
>   can prove control of the domain. For example, the CA might give the
>   agent a choice of either:
>
> - Provisioning a DNS record under example.com, or
> - Provisioning an HTTP resource under a well-known URI on http://example.com/

Comment: But do an email like gmail.com be considers for sure that its from domain gmail.com ?
Or a hacker can send email on some one's behalf too ?

Comment: Sorry for that, however I am not able to comprehend it. I am trying to think about a simple solution that I will send an excrypted message [using public key of domain] and send it to the claimed email address, if the mail replies me with the solved decrypyted message, I can ensure its a verified account. Derived this from Lets'encyrpt.com reference only. Will this be a good start ?

Comment: No. "I have a Gmail account, but I certainly don't control gmail.com." (Well, not unless the "public key of domain" you refer to is one you convinced the controller of the DNS to set up in the DNS records… but involving emails at that stage is rather pointless)

Comment: @AnuragVohra You seem to be trying to reinvent OpenPGP and S/MIME. Don't. Use existing tools and standards.